# Adding RGB values to Laspy synthetic point generation?

Tags: python, lidar, las, rgb, laspy

What is the correct way to add RGB values to points made from scratch?

Laspy is working great for me so far. I want to add RGB values to synthetic points that I've generated. I am using 2 numpy arrays. The first stores all of the XYZ (floats) values. The second array stores the point data record (intensity, classification; Red, Green, Blue). There are only 1200 points and they classify fine. When I comment out the "RGB" the file is generated.

Code:

```
def makeLASfile(finishPoints,LASheader, valuesP):
    #From laspy
    print("Your Making LAS file")
        
    outfile = laspy.file.File("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\Programming\\Python Scripts\\Laspy\\Circleoutput.las", mode="w", header=LASheader)
    outfile.header.offset = LASheader.offset
    outfile.header.scale = [0.001,0.001,0.001]
    
    outfile.x = finishPoints[ :,0]
    outfile.y = finishPoints[ :,1]
    outfile.z = finishPoints[ :,2]
    
    outfile.intensity=valuesP[ :,0] #intensity 
    outfile.flag_byte=valuesP[ :,1] #flag_byte
    outfile.Raw_Classification = valuesP[ :,2] #classification
    outfile.user_data = valuesP[ :,3] #user_data
    outfile.pt_src_id = valuesP[ :,4] #pt_src_id
    outfile.Red = valuesP[ :,5] #red
    #outfile.green=valuesP[ :,6] #green
    #outfile.blue = valuesP[ :,7] #blue 
    
    outfile.close()
```

The issue is that I have something not formatted correctly for the RGB and I get the following exception:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\laspy\base.py", line 1221, in set_dimension
    spec = self.point_format.lookup[name]
KeyError: 'red'

    self.set_dimension("red", red)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\laspy\base.py", line 1225, in set_dimension
    "not found.")
laspy.util.LaspyException: Dimension: rednot found.*
```

**UPDATE**

https://pointly.ai/how-to-convert-your-point-cloud-data-into-las-laz/
provides a nice 'How-to' using Pandas and Laspy

***Update for laspy 2.0 ***

```
        rgbinfo = (255,127,0)
        red, green, blue = rgbinfo       
        classify = 10
        intensity = 16000            
        point_count = point_array.shape[0]
        print(point_array.shape)            
        print(f'Main las file points = {point_count}')
        filler = np.empty((point_count,1), dtype = int)
        pointrecord = laspy.create(file_version="1.2", point_format=3)
        pointrecord.header.offsets = np.min(point_array, axis=0)
        pointrecord.header.scales = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
        pointrecord.header.generating_software = "SSI_RoadScan"
        pointrecord.header.point_count = point_count
        pointrecord = laspy.create(point_format=3,file_version="1.2") 
        pointrecord.x = point_array[:,0]
        pointrecord.y = point_array[:,1]
        pointrecord.z = point_array[:,2]
        filler.fill(classify)
        pointrecord.classification = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(red)
        pointrecord.red = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(blue)
        pointrecord.blue = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(green)
        pointrecord.green = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(intensity)
        pointrecord.intensity = filler[:,0]
        pointrecord.write(filename)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an actual question. As it stands, it's just a statement of what you're working on.

Comment: I used the same code as above. I have a text file that has XYZ and RGB values in it. To convert it to .las format i use lfile = laspy.file.File(r"D:\las\tolas.las", mode='w',header=LasHeader(x_scale=0.01,y_scale=0.01,z_scale=0.01)) header = laspy.header.Header(point_format=2) lfile.x = x/0.01 lfile.y = y/0.01 lfile.z = z/0.01 lfile.set_red = r lfile.set_green = g lfile.set_blue = b lfile.close() But the RGB values are not being set. Where did I go wrong. The las format is 1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header needs to be set with a point format that supports RGB colors, see: https://pythonhosted.org/laspy/tut_background.html. For LAS 1.2, the minimum point format for color is 2:

```
header = laspy.header.Header(point_format=2) # LAS point format 2 supports color

with laspy.file.File(output_path, mode="w", header=header) as lasfile:

    lasfile.header.offset = offset
    lasfile.header.scale = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

    lasfile.x = xs
    lasfile.y = ys
    lasfile.z = zs

    lasfile.red = reds
    lasfile.green = greens
    lasfile.blue = blues
```

By the way, the color calls are property attributes in laspy, so calls to "red" and "set_red" are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I was not using the set method from `laspy` writer. I modified the `Outfile.red`  to `outfile.set_red`.

This makes a nice las 1.2 file from scratch.

Working code:

```
def write_las(self, point_array, filename, info):
    #Creates las files for the calculated points and rawpoints 
    try:
        red, green, blue = info            
        classify = 10
        intensity = 16000
        
        point_count = point_array.shape[0]
        print(point_array.shape)            
        print(f'Main las file points = {point_count}')
        filler = np.empty((point_count,1), dtype = int)
        
        hdr = laspy.header.Header()
        hdr.major_version = 1
        hdr.minor_version = 2
        hdr.version_major = 1
        hdr.version_minor = 2
        
        outfile = laspy.file.File(filename, mode="w", header = hdr)
        
        xmin = np.floor(np.min(point_array[:,0]))
        ymin = np.floor(np.min(point_array[:,1]))
        zmin = np.floor(np.min(point_array[:,2]))
        
        outfile.header.offset = [xmin, ymin, zmin]
        outfile.header.scale = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
        outfile.header.global_encoding = 9
        outfile.x = point_array[:,0]
        outfile.y = point_array[:,1]
        outfile.z = point_array[:,2]
        filler.fill(classify)
        outfile.classification = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(red)
        outfile.red = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(blue)
        outfile.blue = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(green)
        outfile.green = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(intensity)
        outfile.intensity = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(0)
        outfile.return_num = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(3)
        outfile.num_returns = filler[:,0]
        filler.fill(48658)
        outfile.pt_src_id = filler[:,0]
        
        '''
        Intensity unsigned short 2 bytes
        Return Number 3 bits (bits 0, 1, 2) 3 bits *
        Number of Returns (given pulse) 3 bits (bits 3, 4, 5) 3 bits *
        Scan Direction Flag 1 bit (bit 6) 1 bit *
        Edge of Flight Line 1 bit (bit 7) 1 bit *
        Classification unsigned char 1 byte *
        Scan Angle Rank (-90 to +90) – Left side unsigned char 1 byte *
        User Data unsigned char 1 byte
        Point Source ID unsigned short 2 bytes *
        '''
        outfile.close()

        print(f'Completed {filename} \n')
       
        return
```