# Adding RGB values from a .txt file to a .las file using laspy

Tags: python, lidar, las, rgb, laspy

I have a text file that has XYZ and RGB values in it. To convert it to .las format i use

```
lfile = laspy.file.File(r"D:\las\tolas.las", mode='w',header=LasHeader(x_scale=0.01,y_scale=0.01,z_scale=0.01))
header = laspy.header.Header(point_format=2)
lfile.x = x/0.01
lfile.y = y/0.01
lfile.z = z/0.01
lfile.set_red = r
lfile.set_green = g
lfile.set_blue = b
lfile.close()
```

But the RGB values are not being set. Where did I go wrong. The las format is 1.2

Comment: It looks like your question may have been answered in this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297304/adding-rgb-values-to-laspy-synthetic-point-generation

Comment: Since that is a different thread, I asked as another question here.