# Laspy outfile gives zero decimal points in coordinates

Tags: python, classification, laspy

Im detecting trees and want to create a .las file to be able to display it in Cloud Compare. I can not wrap my head around why this is not working. The scale should allow for 6 decimal points but it is rounded to the nearest int each time.

```
    outFile = File("trees.las", mode="w", header=ransac.dataFile.header)

    print(trees[:, 0])
    print(type(trees[:, 0]))
    print(outFile.header.scale)

    outFile.X = trees[:, 0]

    print(outFile.X)

    outFile.Y = trees[:, 1]
    outFile.Z = trees[:, 2]
    outFile.close()
```

This is the printed values

```
[77.679703 77.6772   77.675003 ... 78.716003 78.696198 78.674599]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[1e-06, 1e-06, 1e-06]
[77 77 77 ... 78 78 78]
```

All help will be appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all you have to do is to change X, Y, Z to not be capital letters like this.

```
    outFile.x = trees[:, 0]
    outFile.y = trees[:, 1]
    outFile.z = trees[:, 2]
```

Comment: Please add to link where this is documented.

Comment: Could not find any documentation just ended up trying it out and it worked

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297304/adding-rgb-values-to-laspy-synthetic-point-generation/297377#297377

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/laspy/index.html